# how to ensure that each time a css class name changes from the previous, it is applied a specific style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table structure shown below, and I want to make sure that each time a  switches class from 'odd' to 'even' or from 'even' to 'odd', the s inside the row of the new class get applied a certain style. So in the example, the first 'even' row after the 7 odd rows would have s with a greater top padding than the rest, and then, the first 'odd' row after that (7 rows down) would have greater top padding as well.

I can use either css (preferred) or javascript / jquery to accomplish this. How do I make that happen? Note that I do not have the ability to generate the initial table structure in with any different markup than what is shown below.

[image]

---

Table generating function (only concerned with structure of 'newtable'):

```
  $('.table').each(function() {
    var table = $(this); // cache table object
    var head = table.find('thead th');
    var rows = table.find('tbody tr').clone(); 
    var newtable = $(
      '<table class="table mobile">' +
      '  <tbody>' +
      '  </tbody>' +
      '</table>'
    );

    // cache tbody where we'll be adding data
    var newtable_tbody = newtable.find('tbody');

    rows.each(function(i) {
      var cols = $(this).find('td');
      var classname = i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd';

      cols.each(function(k) {
        var new_tr = $('<tr class="' + classname + '"></tr>').appendTo(newtable_tbody);
        var headEl = head.clone().get(k);
        new_tr.append(headEl);
        new_tr.append($(this));
        var isEmpty = $(headEl).hasClass('empty'); //check for table columns being used as headers, make sure they span two columns on mobile so that the regular table data isn't as wide as the column header. Note that this assumes mobile `.table`s will only ever be 2 columns
        if (isEmpty){
          $(this).attr('colspan',2);
        }
      });
    });

    $(this).after(newtable);
  }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the function that changes these classes? If so it is quite easy. If not you will need to observe the DOM for mutations.

Comment: @Ozan - yes, I think I can manipulate that function. I've modified my answer to show the function that generates the `newtable` - note that the function is making a new table from an existing table with a different structure from the first.

Comment: Looking at your question again, there seems to be no need for javascript here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using CSS' `+` `next sibling` selector.

```css
.odd {
  color: red;
}
.even{
  color: blue;
}

tr.odd + tr.even td {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

tr.even + tr.odd td {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Sample Row 01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Sample Row 02</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Sample Row 03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>Sample Row 04</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>Sample Row 05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>Sample Row 06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Sample Row 07</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Sample Row 08</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>Sample Row 09</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Sample Row 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't know in advance the classes but you want to set style to every row that the class has changed, you can use this javascript code:

```js
function checkTblRows(id) {
  var oldClass = undefined;
  
  $('#' + id).find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    if (oldClass === undefined) {
      oldClass = $(el).attr('class')
      return;
    }
    if (oldClass == $(el).attr('class')) {
      oldClass = $(el).attr('class')
      return;
    } else {
      oldClass = $(el).attr('class')
      $(el).css({color: 'red'});
    }
  });
}
$(function() {
  checkTblRows('tbl1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr class="a">
    <td>Class a</td>
  </tr><tr class="a">
    <td>Class a</td>
  </tr><tr class="a">
    <td>Class a</td>
  </tr><tr class="a">
    <td>Class a</td>
  </tr><tr class="b">
    <td>Class b</td>
  </tr><tr class="b">
    <td>Class b</td>
  </tr><tr class="a">
    <td>Class a</td>
  </tr><tr class="a">
    <td>Class a</td>
  </tr><tr class="a">
    <td>Class a</td>
  </tr><tr class="b">
    <td>Class b</td>
  </tr><tr class="b">
    <td>Class b</td>
  </tr><tr class="c">
    <td>Class c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```